# how to programmaticaly remove the top bar and left bar on ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

everythings is in the title. I'm looking for series of command I can do only from a terminal, and if possible, for all users.
I don't want to user gnome-shell for weird raisons (virt-viewer works much better within complete gnome)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: So ... you want to remove the Desktop Panel bar (kill ?  or hide ?) from visible screen, from within a program, which is initiated by the owner of the Desktop.  Correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out it was only a configuration file that I had to change: /usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json to do the trick.

Sorry for the inconvenance